# Problems with games on-line in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, games

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and used to play games that now suddenly I cannot play,
Those games are: LEGEND ON LINE and LEAGUE OF ANGELS via facebook games.
Before install 14.04 LTS i can play these games, but now no.
With another games via facebook, I have not any problem,
I would like to solve this little trance
Thanks in advance to all
Alfil Bermello

Comment: Xubuntu 14.04: I just tried those games using the built in Firefox and they play fine for me. However, I am using the XFCE Desktop on Ubuntu, the Xubuntu flavor. So that may make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

Try playing the games in Chromium browser. Since both League of Angels and Legend Online are Flash Player games, maybe you'll have better results using the more up-to-date Pepper flash player in Chromium browser. Install Pepper flash player by following the instructions from [Get latest Flash player on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524279/get-latest-flash-player-on-ubuntu/548047#548047).

Comment: I've done what you've shown me and the terminal tells me:

"Pepperflashplugin-nonfree" package has no installation candidate

The case is that I normally use chromium but I put the code if missing pepperflash

Comment: btw: If you search for Chromium Web Browser in the Ubuntu Software Center and click "More Info" you will find both Chromium and the pepperflashplugin checkbox on the same screen. It might be easier for you to install them both that way. Also you got the terminal error because the pepperflashplugin package is case sensitive so you got the error message because of the capital **P** in Pepper...

Comment: By entering the code,

sudo apt-get install chromium-browser pepperflashplugin-nonfree

The terminal returns me the following message:

Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done
The pepperflashplugin-nonfree package is not available, although outro refers to the package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted or is made available só other source.

Comment: Close the terminal and try it again in the Ubuntu Software Center. The Pepper Flash Player is there on the same screen as the Chromium Web Browser (after you press the More Info button to get to the  Chromium Web Browser More Info screen) at the bottom of the screen in the Optional addons section. Mark the checkbox and click the Apply Changes button to install Pepper Flash Player.

Comment: I only have one addon on chromium-browser "Browser plugin for DjVu image format (diview-plugin)
The Pepper Flash Player does not exit in Ubuntu Software Centes

Comment: I added more info to my answer about how to show three more Optional addons for Chromium Web Browser.

Comment: Where is it? I can see karel¡¡¡

Comment: Go to *Dash* -> *Software & Updates* -> *Ubuntu Software* tab. It should be there (like what I added to my answer). The Dash is opened by clicking the round purple and white icon at the top of the Launcher.

Comment: xoanton@xoanton-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt-get install chromium-browser pepperflashplugin-nonfree
[sudo] password for xoanton: 
Reading lists of bundles... Fact
Construyenndo tree of dependencies       
Reading information do state... Fact
The bundle pepperflashplugin-nonfree is not dispoñíbel, but another bundle alludes to.
This can mean that the bundle is absent, it is obsolete or it is only disponíble another source.

E: The bundle "pepperflashplugin-nonfree" does not have an installation candidate
xoanton@xoanton-System-Product-Name: ~ $

Comment: Answer of teminal

Comment: That's why I told you to use the graphical applications instead, so you can see what you're doing instead of getting a list of confusing error messages in the terminal. All the error messages are saying is that you have to add the Software Source that has Pepper Flash Player to your list of Software Sources. This can be done with the Software & Updates utility. If you can get as far as opening the Software & Updates utility, you will see that it looks the same as what I put in my answer - a list with five items and you have to put check marks in the first four checkboxes.

Comment: The software sources is all activated than you say me, but the software center only take an addon in chromium¡¡¡¡

Comment: At least you've got your normal Software Sources activated, even if you haven't got Legend Online and League of Angels working.

Comment: But I can play these games before, in one time, they cannot play.
I don"t quit pepperflash¡¡

Comment: It's a frustrating problem. It's like you have two different problems: 1) You can't play those 2 games. 2) You can't install Pepper Flash Player. Maybe these 2 problems are related, caused by the same thing and maybe they're not. The only way to know for sure is to install Pepper Flash Player, but you can't install Pepper Flash Player.

Comment: Update: Pepper Flash Player - browser plugin no longer appears under the **Optional add-ons** heading on the Chromium Web Browser page in the Ubuntu Software Center for Ubuntu 14.04. It now has its own separate page in the Ubuntu Software Center. And there are two packages available: pepperflashplugin-nonfree for Ubuntu 64-bit and pepperflashplugin-nonfree:i386 for Ubuntu 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you are using firefox then go to

> help > Troubleshoot information > reset firefox

Firefox gets reset.

Then install/Reinstall Adobe Flash from repo.
visit https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/adobe-flashplugin/

Execute the update and upgrade command via terminal.