# Flash Player on TSN.ca

Tags: flash

I have tried everything i can to get the flash on tsn.ca to work, but no luck.
On all other sites, from youtube, facebook, nhl.com etc- the flash works. But on tsn.ca they tell me to install flashplayer.
Ive tried with Wine, no luck , with the Software Center, no luck. With answers on these treads here on internet.. No luck.

Does it work with you?
TSN.ca or TSN.com , the videos on the right side, or this to the Video Hub:
http://www.tsn.ca/VideoHub/?collection=72&show=444612

thanks

Comment: Tried with Google Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

The videos from http://www.tsn.ca/VideoHub/?collection=72&show=444612 work for me using Pepper Flash Player 14.0.0.177 in Chromium web browser, but not with Adobe Flash Player in Firefox.

The reason why the video doesn't work for you is probably because of the advertisements preceding the video. If your flash player is not up to date, then it may be unable to load the advertisements (there are sometimes multiple advertisements) and then load the video after the advertisements have finished playing. The current version of Adobe Flash Player in Firefox is 11.2.202.406. Some other flash content, such as some flash-based Facebook games, also does not work with Adobe Flash Player 11.

Chromium web browser can be installed using the Ubuntu Software Center. You can also install the latest version of Pepper Flash Player (the same flash player that is used in Google Chrome) in Chromium web browser by following the instructions in [Get latest Flash player on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524279/get-latest-flash-player-on-ubuntu).