# Youtube videos on Firefox not playing properly

Tags: 14.04, firefox, video, youtube

I've reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 multiple times because Youtube videos haven't been playing properly. I thought maybe reinstalling Ubuntu might help but apparently it hasn't. During video playback, the video suddenly becomes jerky and unwatchable. This happens randomly. How do I get this fixed?

The laptop I'm using Ubuntu on is a Dell 13" 7348 core i7.

Comment: Did you try another browser such as chromuim, chrome, epiphany etc...

Comment: have you tried disabling prefetching in about:config? for some reason, this seems to help prevent "glitch" type artifacts for html5 videos on firefox using intel graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three suggestion for improving the playing of YouTube videos in Firefox.

1. Some models of the Dell Inspiron 13" 7348 Notebook have an NVIDIA graphics card, but most of the Dell 13" 7348 models don't have an NVIDIA graphics card. From the Dash search for *Additional Drivers*, open the Additional Drivers utility, and check if there is a proprietary NVIDIA graphics driver in the list of additional drivers that are available to be installed on your computer.

   If there is a proprietary NVIDIA graphics driver in the list of additional drivers, you can identify the Recommended driver to be installed from the terminal by running the command:

   ```
   ubuntu-drivers devices
   ```
2. Try enabling the YouTube HTML5 Video Player. From Firefox visit the [YouTube HTML5 Video Player](https://www.youtube.com/html5) website and click the large blue button that says **Request the HTML5 player**.
3. Try watching the YouTube videos in Chromium browser. Maybe you'll have better results using the more up-to-date Pepper Flash Player in Chromium browser. Install Pepper Flash Player - browser plugin (*pepperflashplugin-nonfree*) from the Ubuntu Software Center.

   When you install Pepper Flash Player - browser plugin, it will download Google Chrome and unpack it to make the included Pepper Flash Player available for use with Chromium. The latest version of Pepper Flash Player is 18.0.0.209 compared to 11.2.202.491 for Adobe Flash Player in Firefox. The instructions for updating Pepper Flash Player to the latest version are in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524279/get-latest-flash-player-on-ubuntu/548047#548047).

   *Update*

   These instructions will install Pepper flash player for Chromium and it will also be updated automatically. In addition to installing flash player for Chromium, it will also install/reinstall Adobe flash player for Firefox, and it will also be updated automatically. Because Google ended support for Chrome on 32-bit Linux in March, 2016, Pepper flash player can only be installed for 64-bit versions of Chromium.

   To install flash player in Chromium web browser search the Dash for Software & Updates and open the Software & Updates window. Click the *Other Software* tab in the Software & Updates window and put a check mark in the checkbox to the left of where it says: **Canonical Partners**.

   [image]

   Click the *Close* button to close the Software & Updates window.

   Open the terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update  
   sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin  
   sudo apt install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash # 16.04 and later
   ```

Comment: I've downloaded and installed pepper flash but it hasn't downloaded chrome. Will I have to download and install that separately?

Comment: No, you won't have to install Chrome separately or at all. The reason why it downloads Chrome is in order to unpack only Pepper Flash Player, and it doesn't do anything else with Chrome except for unpacking and then installing Pepper Flash Player. Afterwards you can ignore Google Chrome because it has not been installed on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube use HTML5 now, so the control (play, stop, volume) is in ECMAscript. You can set `dom.max_script_run_time` to the value 20 in `about:config`. Look how you can do this right at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/warning-unresponsive-script