# Chromium hates flash?

Tags: 14.04, flash, chromium

I've recently installed chromium at the suggestion of some friends and I like it. but I can't get it to install a flash plugin so I can watch hulu and netflix. I tried installing pepper flash from the software center. I tried installing adobe-flash plugin player from cannonical partners. I've tried installing them via the terminal and I've rebooted my system and browsers.

when I type chrome://flash into the address bar it says I don't have a flash plugin in installed and that I have no graphics card.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/524279/get-latest-flash-player-on-ubuntu/548047#548047 about how to install the latest version of flash player in Chromium (the latest version is 18). It might help.

Comment: this thread is everywhere and just keeps on talking in circles about chrome. I need something for chromium

Comment: I'm sorry to disappoint you, but the default Ubuntu repositories have only the Pepper Flash Player (*pepperflashplugin-nonfree*) for Chromium. Pepper Flash Player is used in both Google Chrome and Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install Google Chrome browser to be able to watch netflix. Google Chrome supports netflix, don't know with hulu.

I haven't used both, netflix and hulu, but a few months ago, there was a news but Google Chrome is now able to play netflix directly from their browser (regardless of the OS), don't know with hulu though.

Comment: Remove the "I think", sounds like you were giving a suggestion and also worth mention Google Chrome comes with flash plugin while chromium, being an open source project, doesn't.

Comment: "I think" coz I've never actually used netflix nor hulu. It's not available for my country. I've just read it somewhere that Chrome does able to play netflix. I even read from PCLINUXOS website before about Chrome update that's now able to play netflix from their OS. "I think" again that it's not just on PCLINUXOS but on other desktop OS as well. And yes, it's a suggestion.