# Ubuntu freezes when exiting YouTube full screen

Tags: google-chrome, 15.10, youtube, fullscreen

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 and Chrome Version 48.0.2564.82 (64-bit) with Intel HD 5500 graphics.

The computer will freeze when I exit a YouTube video from full screen.  You can start to see the desktop, but a still frame from the video will be frozen over ~70% of the screen.  The odd part is I can still hear the audio playing, I just have no controls and a reboot has been the only fix.

What I have tried so far:

- Disabling Override software rendering list
- With or without the proprietary driver. The Intel HD 5500 is the "graphics card". I thought the issue could be graphics related, so that is why I tried swapping the drivers.
- I tried disabling hardware acceleration, but the video does not really
  play with it off.

Comment: If the Intel HD 5500 is the "graphics card" of your computer, then you should use the built-in graphics driver that is preinstalled in Ubuntu without a proprietary graphics driver.

Comment: Thanks Karel.  I have tried the preinstalled and the proprietary. Both create the same issue of crashing when exiting full screen.

Comment: I have updated my Chromium web browser (Chromium is in the Ubuntu Software Center) to the same version as your Chrome 48.0.2564.82 using Ubuntu's Software Updater. Since Chromium is the identical version as your Chrome, does the same problem also occur in Chromium? You need to install Flash player separately in Chromium and then update it by following the instructions in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/524279/get-latest-flash-player-on-ubuntu/548047#548047).